# ILMerge: How to configure the corresponding app.config

Tags: c#, app-config, ilmerge

I'm just trying ILMerge to merge my application and the needed libraries into one executable. I'm using the command line just to do some testing. I took a sample project:

```
ilmerge /out:ProgramMerged.exe Program.exe Lib1.dll Lib2.dll
```

This seems to work as intended. But what if I had a `Program.exe.config`? Is it still applicable?

Does anybody how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The config file is always called the same as the EXE file + .config. So if you "rename" Program.exe to ProgramMerged.EXE you need to copy/rename program.exe.config to programmerged.exe.config

Comment: Thanks Arve, I didn't try the obvious one... Indeed one just needs to rename the app.config, no need to change anything internal, it seems.

Comment: Seems obvious in hindsight but never saw it documented anywhere.  A +1 hopefully it saves someone else some time.